# Make single line independent of table pattern

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I got this table right here:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
    Metric / Index & \textbf{V1 - Base Unet} & \textbf{V2 - Multiscale} & \textbf{V3 - Attention} \\
    \midrule
    
    Training set \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
    Validation set \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
    Test set \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I center the "Training set", "Validation set" and "Test set" quotes that they are also independent of the `lccc` pattern of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `multicolumn` for centering individual cells.

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
    Metric / Index & \textbf{V1 - Base Unet} & \textbf{V2 - Multiscale} & \textbf{V3 - Attention} \\
    \midrule
    
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Training set} \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Validation set} \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Test set} \\
    \midrule
    MAE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are two approaches to "fixing up" the table.

- The first centers the strings "Training set", "Validation set", and "Test set" across the three data columns via

  ```
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{...}
  ```

  wrappers, followed by `\cmidrule(l){2-4}` directives to provide some visual grouping. The result is OK, I suppose, but one might question the need to **bold-face** some of the header cells.
- The second approach is quite different. First, it creates a new header column, arranges the "set" strings to span *both* the new and the existing header column, and places the MAE, MSE, etc strings in column 2, so that they become visually subordinate to the "set" strings. This provides some much-needed visual grouping for the two categories of objects. Second, it also provides for more formal structure in the header *row* and does away with the unnecessary **bold-facing**. Overall, the table now has a much more compact "look" than before; many readers will find the compact look quite appealing.

Choose your pick. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[vmargin=1in]{geometry} % just for this example
\usepackage{booktabs}
% handy shortcut macro for use in second table:
\newcommand\ml[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l ccc @{}}
    \toprule
    Metric/Index 
    & \textbf{V1 -- Base Unet} & \textbf{V2 -- Multiscale} & \textbf{V3 -- Attention} \\
    \midrule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Training set} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
    MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \addlinespace
    & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Validation set} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
    MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \addlinespace
    & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Test set} \\
    \cmidrule(l){2-4}
    MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!] % 'h!' forces the table onto the same pages
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{1ex} l ccc @{}} % new fixed-width left-hand column
    \toprule
    \ml{Set/Metric} 
    & V1 & V2 & V3 \\
    & & Base Unet & Multiscale & Attention \\
    \midrule
    
    \ml{Training set} \\
    & MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \addlinespace
    
    \ml{Validation set} \\
    & MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \addlinespace
    
    \ml{Test set} \\
    & MAE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & MSE  & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & SSIM & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    & ZNCC & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label_x}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First sample looks quite neat :)

Comment: @CaipiDE I'd go with the last one, but with the keywords in italic